# Edit axes appearance on surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface

My code plots a surface plot for the below data. I want to change the appearance of X and Y axis. Right now it displays only 10 and 100. How can I edit it so that it displays values between them as well? I haven't understood the use of tickformatter in the code, I had received the suggestion from one of the member on the forum for my previous question.

(Please note: Image for reresentation purposes, the below data gives similar image but with different values)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter, FuncFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np

def format_log(x, pos=None):
    x1 = 10**x
    s = "%.3f" % x1
    return s[:-4] if s[-3:]=="000" else " "

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X=[2,3,5,8,20,30,50,80,100,150,175,200,250,300]
Y=[2,3,4,5,10,15,20,30,40,50,80,100,125,150,175,200]
X = np.log10(np.array(X))
Y = np.log10(np.array(Y))
Y,X=np.meshgrid(Y,X)
Z=np.array([
[0.2885307,0.269452,0.259193,0.2548041,0.2731868,0.4801551,0.7992361,1.7577641,3.2611327,5.428839,19.647976,37.59729,78.0871,152.21466,268.14572,0],
[0.2677955,0.2538363,0.2380033,0.2306999,0.4779794,0.9251045,1.5448972,3.508644,6.4968576,11.252151,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0.2432982,0.2283371,0.2514196,0.3392502,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0.2342575,0.3158406,0.4770729, 0.6795485,2.353042, 5.260077,9.78172,25.87004,59.52568, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0.6735384, 1.3873291,2.346506, 3.5654,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1.3584715, 2.9405127,5.096819,8.155857,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[3.558062,8.216592,15.768077,27.386694,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[9.537899,25.202589,58.20041,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[16.083374,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[54.936775,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[89.185974,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
my_col = cm.jet(Z/np.amax(Z))
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.set_zlim(0, 300)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_log))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_log))
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with specifying all ticks manually, you can just add something like

```py
ax.set_xticks([np.log10(x) for x in [10, 20, 60, 100]])
ax.set_yticks([np.log10(y) for y in [10, 30, 60, 100]])
```

Besides, you can follow the "progress" on the 3D-log scale issue [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209).